# Fetch distinct record from table 1 on join with table 2 in mysqli & php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to fetch data from two tables (questions & answers) with question_id as foreign key but i am getting multiple question records. My answers table contain multiple records with same question_id and the output getting question record as answer value times. How can i avoid it, Please help.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(questions.question),answers.answers FROM questions INNER JOIN answers ON questions.question_id = answers.question_id" ;
     $result = $connection->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $question = $row['question'];
            $answers = $row['answers'];
?>
```

Printing results here...

Comment: Your query is doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing.  You need to edit your question and specify what you want it to do.

Comment: I want to get question only single time with corresponding answer values as array elements for that question_id.

Comment: Bit of a side note here. It isn't wise to store html markup tags. You should use those during output. HTML/PHP/MySQL are different animals and should be treated as such. You would also reduce the amount of data in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(questions.question), answers.answers
FROM questions INNER JOIN
     answers
     ON questions.question_id = answers.question_id;
```

My first observation is that you don't understand `DISTINCT`.  `SELECT DISTINCT` is a keyword.  The `DISTINCT` modifies the `SELECT`.  It is not a function.

Second, your query is defining a result set that has one row per question and answer.  This is eminently reasonable -- and the `DISTINCT` is not necessary.

I suspect that you want the answers on a single row.  Of course, you can do that in PHP.  You can also use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT q.question, GROUP_CONCAT(a.answers SEPARATOR '|') as answers
FROM questions q INNER JOIN
     answers a
     ON q.question_id = a.question_id
GROUP BY q.question;
```

Note that use of table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: As the answer options are not same, i can't use GROUP_CONCAT right? This will getting only one answer option for each question.

Comment: @PrudhviMallavarapu . .. Did you try the query?  It combines the answers into a single string.

Comment: I forgot to keep 'AS' after GROUP_CONCAT.   I got it now, Thanks.